# How to take MySQL data and read it into an Android App

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have a website in which I have a very simple html form that I can fill out. The page was made using php and mysql, so it is also password protected. On this form, I accept input for "Data" and "Activity". With this very small system:

- I can log in with a password
- Enter a "Date" and "Activity"
- The "Date" and "Activity" are stored in a MySQL database

At this point, I think I will just have to build a JSON parser, which there already are many tutorials on this. Such as [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). what's confusing to me is how to create this JSON page. None of the tutorials really show you how to create a JSON array of the data you are looking for.

This may be a very basic question, but I still very new to Java, PHP, MySQL and totally new to JSON. Please educate me on this topic.

### Update:

This code worked for me in the end

```
<?php
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_db", "password");

   mysql_select_db("my_table") or die(mysql_error());


$sql=mysql_query("select * from activity");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the built-in PHP function `json_encode`

You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

If you run a query from PHP like this: `SELECT Activity, Date from YourTable where field = value`

Then you can use json_encode: `echo json_encode($result)`

It will output something like this `{"Activity":"Activity Text","Date":"ExampleDate"}`

Comment: Oh! So what you're saying is I create a webpage like: abc.com/myjson.php that runs a query and encodes it into JSON?

Comment: As long as you do proper validation and error handling it'll be enough, yes.

Comment: Okay two more things... #1: Can you explain "proper validation and error handling" and #2: I was confused with JSON because a lot of JSON links I see end with .json (like https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/example.json) How do I make my php webpage a JSON webpage?

Comment: From the basic stuff: Be sure the parameters are in the type you need (int, string, etc) If it's a string it might or not require an specific format. As for 'error handling' I meant what you'd want to do in case something fails, or if you are going to print error messages.

About the files ending in .json I don't think there's any way to do a "JSON webpage", I think they are pretty much normal .php files but renamed using .htaccess for readability.

Comment: Great, that's where I'll start. I'll see if I can device a quick php script to output JSON.

Comment: Great it worked. I changed the code a tiny bit, but now I get a JSON output. I'm going to try to parse it into my android app now. Thank you

Comment: As Areks mentioned, Simply json_encode() the query result @server side and in your android code use some classes or packages that helps to parse the json response example jsonObject and jsonArray. For more you can check this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/